# sonata admin datagrid filter autocomplete for 'doctrine_orm_callback'

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have `Licence` with relation to `SchoolClass` with relation to `School`. I want to filter Licence by School. I managed to do this with this:

```
$datagridMapper
->add(
    'school',
    'doctrine_orm_callback',
    [
        'label' => 'Mokykla',
        'show_filter' => true,
        'callback' => function ($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
            if (!$value['value']) {
                return false;
            }

            $queryBuilder
                ->join($alias.'.schoolClass', 'schoolClass')
                ->join('schoolClass.school', 'school')
                ->andWhere('school.name LIKE :value')
                ->setParameter('value', '%'.$value['value'].'%')
            ;

            return true;
        },
    ],
    'entity',
    [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:School',
    ]
);
```

### Problem

While this is working it is loading all School choices to filter dropdown box so page is slow. Autocomplete (as 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete') would be better. However I was not able to make it work.